# How i am must test this method with mockito?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

Method in service class:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Collection<Account> searchAccounts(String partOfName) {
    Collection<Account> accounts = accountDao.getAll();
    CollectionUtils.filter(accounts, account ->
            account.getName().toLowerCase().contains(partOfName.toLowerCase()) ||
                    account.getSurname().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(partOfName.toLowerCase()));
    return accounts;
}
```

I am not understand what i must do with CollectionUtils.filter. mock this too?
Now i have this in test class:

```
@Test
public void searchAccountsByPartOfName() {
    service.searchAccounts("test");
    verify(accountDao, times(1)).getAll();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to mock `CollectionUtils.filter()`.  You might need to mock `accountDao`, however, so that when you call its `getAll()` method you get a collection of `Account`s back.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese Account collection probably will changed after CollectionUtils.filter in real program, it is not matter?

Comment: that is precisely what you are trying to test, right?  You are trying to test that your filtering method works, so it is expected that `CollectionUtils.filter()` will modify the `Collection` that gets returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CollectionUtils.filter` is a utility method that filter a collection based on the predicate. You don't need to mock that.

What you need to do is to mock `accountDao` to return a `Collection<Account>`. The account instances in the collection can be real objects or mocks. If it is a simple POJO, I recommend creating a list of real Account objects.

Then, you verify the returned `Collection<Account>` from the list in that it correctly filters out the Account objects as per the predicate.

With this, you are testing the crux of your code/logic.

It might look like this (disclaimer: not compiled)

```
@Test
public void searchAccountsByPartOfName() throws ParseException {
    Collection<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    Account acc1 = new new Account(..); //name having the substring "test"
    Account acc2 = new new Account(..); //surname equals "test"
    Account acc3 = new new Account(..);  //neither name nor surname has the substring "test"
    accounts.add(acc1); 
    accounts.add(acc2); 
    accounts.add(acc3);

    when(accountDao.getAll()).thenReturn(accounts);

    service.searchAccounts("test");

    Collection<Account> actual = service.searchAccounts("test");

    //here assert that the actual is of size 2 and it has the ones that pass the predicate
    assertEquals(2, actual.size());
    assertEquals(acc1, actual.get(0));
    assertEquals(acc2, actual.get(1));
}
```

You might also want to write similar tests to test the case insensitve checks.

Comment: @diofloyk Initially I thought it removes the ones that pass the predicate. But it does the opposite. I have updated the answer

Comment: Hello user7, just a side note : in a general way `assertEquals(acc1, actual.get(0));`  is not necessarily the best way to perform assertions. AssertJ/Hamcrest are designed to solve this point. You have my vote whatever.

Comment: @davidxxx Do you mean using assertEquals passing the expected collection?

Comment: No I mean `Assertions.assertThat(actual ).extracting(Account::getName, Account::getSurname).containsExactly(tuple(acc1.getName(), acc1.getSurname()), tuple(acc2.getName(), acc2.getSurname()))` Look at "Assertions on extracted properties/fields of iterable/array elements" in https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html. All of that spares you to couple equals() with assertions that are two distinct things.

Comment: @davidxxx Thx for note and answer, looks useful.

Comment: @davidxxx ah. I see. I haven't used them. Will look into them. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The `CollectionUtils.filter()` invocation contains the logic performed by the `searchAccounts()` method while `Collection<Account> accounts = accountDao.getAll();` is the part of `searchAccounts()` that you want to isolate as performed by another dependency.
So mock `accountDao()` to return a specific list of account and assert that `searchAccounts()` returns the expected filtered accounts.